# How to get similar address suggestions in FedEx address validation web services?

Tags: c#, fedex

I am working with FedEx Address Validation web services. I have come to know that when an address is incorrect it should prompt me for some correct address suggestions.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3):

Per the API spec, it returns multiple results back which you should iterate thru and display to the user, and then re-validate.

> You receive multiple address results when an exact match was not
>   found.   You should confirm an address for accuracy before using it to
>   ship a package.  To narrow your results, you can provide more specific
>   address information and check the address again.

Comment: can you please provide some code block that helps to achieve  what you have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct corrected suggested address from FedEx service.
You can download the service code from the FedEx site in your desired language.
and after validating the address the service returns multiple attributes like:

1. CountrySupported: true
2. ZIP11Match: true
3. SuiteRequiredButMissing: true
4. InvalidSuiteNumber: false
5. MultipleMatches: false
6. Resolved: true
7. ZIP4Match: true
8. DPV: false
9. ValidMultiUnit: false
10. POBox: false
11. MultiUnitBase: true
12. StreetAddress: false
13. POBoxOnlyZIP: false
14. UniqueZIP: false
15. SplitZIP: false
16. RRConversion: false

On the basics of these attributes, you can look at why your address validation failed.
Detail of each attribute you can find on the FedEx Address Validation service documentation file.